# Invalid Slug version in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, devops

I am trying to create a kubernetes cluster with terraform but it shows me an error, I changed the value of the **version** on different occasions but it did not work.

```
resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "lox" {
  name    = "lox"
  region  = "nyc1"
  version = "1.13.4-do.0"

  node_pool {
    name       = "worker-pool"
    size       = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
    node_count = 2
  }
```

This is the error:

```
Error: Error creating Kubernetes cluster: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/kubernetes/clusters: 422 validation error: invalid version slug

  on 01-cluster.tf line 1, in resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "lox":
   1: resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "lox" {
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use below command to grab the latest and valid version slug and use it in `version`

```
doctl kubernetes options versions
```

Answer (score 2):

The version you're setting does not exist.

Check here: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/changelog/ for all the versions available, or using the `doctl` command line.

If you're targeting 1.13, you may use `1.13.12-do.8` as the version, released on 22/06/2020.

Answer (score 0):

i wasn't able to find the version in changelog, found it here https://slugs.do-api.dev/ (tab "Kubernetes versions")

Answer (score 0):

```
doctl kubernetes options versions                                                                                                                   
Slug            Kubernetes Version    Supported Features
1.24.4-do.0     1.24.4                cluster-autoscaler, docr-integration, ha-control-plane, token-authentication
1.23.10-do.0    1.23.10               cluster-autoscaler, docr-integration, ha-control-plane, token-authentication
1.22.13-do.0    1.22.13               cluster-autoscaler, docr-integration, ha-control-plane, token-authentication
```